# Static Value Getting Lost

Tags: java, servlets, static

I am working Servlet based application. Here in the constructor i am initializing a few static variables (ArrayList, HashTable, String etc). But when trying to fetch later, i see all of them showing null. The only thing I have changed over in recent times is changed the WebSphere's deployment to be Parent_Last.

For example, in the constructor I have:

```
private static Map<String, Map<String, String>> systemMappingFilesAsMap;

ConfigUtils () {
    
    super();
    ConfigUtils.systemMappingFilesAsMap = getSystemMap();
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I checked in Eclipse debugger, that the value is getting populated. But later on when i try to do anything with the variable, i see it as null. Hence it throws a `NullPointerException`.

```
return ConfigUtils.systemMappingFilesAsMap.get(mappingFileKey);
```

I am not sure whether its the server configuration change that broke this code, or something I did that doesn't work. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you're accessing the variable before you've created an instance of `ConfigUtils`?

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace of the exception to your question.

Comment: You've multiple instances of the physical `ConfigUtils.class` file throughout the runtime classpath. Most probably one in webapp and another one in server itself. Just cleanup your runtime classpath and ensure it doesn't contain duplicate class files.

Comment: @tgdavies That shouldn't be the case, These values are initialized at server startup. And fetched only when the webapges are accessed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to initialized the variable right away rather than through a constructor? i.e. `private static Map<String, Map<String, String>> systemMappingFilesAsMap = getSystemMap();`?

Comment: @BalusC I was pondering the something similar might be the case. But I am not sure how to do that. If you can point me on how to do it, that might be helpful.

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke Actually it is is being called from different places at different times. So calling the constructor seemed to be the logical way to go about it.

Comment: That's not answerable based on the information provided so far. Your best bet is debugging/logging `ConfigUtils.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` both times and comparing its outcome.

Comment: @BalusC I will give that a try post back. Thanks for the info.

Comment: If setting it in the constructor is the most logical place (i.e. there are multiple instances), then why is the `Map` static?

Comment: @BalusC I checked both times it gives the same output. I added it to the constructor and it shows `file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/PALBASE/server1/sharedlib/cgsshared.jar` and in the method it has the same value.